# Adjusting IntelliJ IDEA plugins for java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

(I'm a beginner and I want to make "small" java projects).
I want to make IntelliJ run faster, so I want to cancel all the plugins that I'm not going to use.

The plugins:
1.build tools: Ant, Maven, Gradle.
2.version controls: CVS, Git, Github, hg4idea, subversion.
3.Test tools: Junits, TestNG-J, Coverage.
4.Swing: UI designer.
And others....

Thanks.

Comment: None of those should impact your performance if you're not using them.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The question is how disabling plugins will make intellij faster, and which ones from those listed to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its true that *all* plugins make IntelliJ start up slower, and many of them can make IntelliJ run slower. If you run with 30 plugins compared to zero - you'll notice the difference.

The best advice is to disable ALL plugins when you install IntelliJ.

Then, you can enable plugins one at a time as you need them.

Need source control? Great, enable `Git` plugin. Need Swing UI? Enable `UI Designer`... you get the idea.

Of those you listed, you probably need *none* of them except `Maven` and `JUint` and a version control plugin (`git` or `svn` or whatever is your cup of tea).

This really is a simple but good advice. For reference: I am a long time intellij user and plugin designer.